# Upgrade 0.9.0 -> 1.4?

Tags: fabric

We're running an ancient version of fabric (0.9.0).  Should I expect any issues if I upgrade to the latest and greatest (1.4?) in a single step?

Answer (score 0):

Some but not many, as the api stayed somewhat consistant. There is a [section in the changelog](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/changelog.html#backwards-incompatible-changes) devoted specifically to this question. There also though is now an lcd() for local dir changes to make the local and remote context managers work independent of one another.